# My sql query is not getting desier result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

These is my attendance table checktype 0 is use as intime and 1 as out time,
i want time as intime for checktype = 0 and time as outtime for checktype = 1
with single entry according date with all empid order by intime will be ascending 
for checktype 0 and descending for checktype 1

i want below type result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to select the smallest intime and largest outtime for each employee per day:

```
select min(case when checktype = 0 then time end) min_intime,
    max(case when checktype = 1 then time end) max_outtime,
    empid,
    date
from mytable
group by empid, date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  bro.

Answer (score 1):

We can use OUTER APPLY in this case to make different set for the selection:

```
select 
    min(t.time) inTime,
    max(t1.time) outTime,
    t.empid,
    t.date
from table1 t
outer apply(select time from table1 t1 where t.empid = t1.empid 
            and t1.checktype = 1) t1
where t.checktype = 0
group by t.empid, t.date
```

Comment: I tried with above query it is given me result but if particular day there is no  intime and out time is present entry will not show in final result using above query logic.